# If the # of people in a room is Poisson distributed, and you observe someone enter, what's the distribution of the # of people?

Tags: probability, distributions, poisson-distribution, conditional-probability

I hope this question is properly formulated. It's just something that occurred to me spontaneously.

Consider a random variable $X$ representing some count data -- for instance, the number of people in a given room at any given time. Suppose we know the distribution of this random variable, e.g., Poisson distributed. Now suppose we observe someone entering or exiting this room (this is the part of the question I'm not sure how to formalize): at this moment, what is the distribution of this random variable (i.e., what's the probability that there are $n$ people in the room)?

Comment: $$X\sim\text{Poisson}(\lambda)$$ Can you write the distribution of $1+X$, perhaps as a pdf using case notation (if ... then... )?

Comment: You haven't clearly stated the temporal aspect of this problem.  Is the Poisson distribution for the number of people in the room as of one specific time, and then there is a one-time increase or decrease by one person in the number of people in the room?  If not that, then what? You may find the process of crisping up the problem definition to help you with the solution.

Comment: My thought is this: for *any* time $t$, the number of people in the room is $X(t) \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda)$ distributed. If you were watching the room all the time, you'd know the actual values for $X(t)$ at all times $t$. Now take time $t_1$: you _observe someone enter or exit the room at that moment_. In the case of someone entering the room, my intuition is that the answer is not $P(X | X >= 1)$ unless $X$ is exponentially distributed. Does that help?

Comment: Perhaps the way to formalize it is this. Suppose that $X(t) \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda)$ for all $t$. Now consider some $t_1$ such that $X(t_1) = X(t_1 - \epsilon) + 1$ for $\epsilon \to 0$. Conditioned on this, what is the distribution of $X(t_1)$? If it makes things easier, we can discretize time.